# Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource with checkbox control in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This error only occurs when I add this following XAML code :
[image]

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ist aktiv" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActiveBool}"  />
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible reasons why you got this error, most (if not all) of which have already been discussed here on StackOverflow. Take a look at the following posts:

[Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996745/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource-in-silverlight)

[Error: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251378/error-items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource)

[Getting an “Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource” with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614339/getting-an-items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource-with-ef)

[DataGridTemplateColumn : Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882306/datagridtemplatecolumn-items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource)

[Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652623/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource)

If you don't find an answer in these posts, perhaps you could do your own search... it is generally preferable for SO users to search *before* they ask questions here.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced a similar problem for the first time, and I noticed you could even get this error message if you have forgot to add/enclose the

```
<DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid.Columns>
```

tags

Comment: This worked for me. Turned out I copied and pasted the `DataGridTemplateColumn` I was using to the wrong place, outside of the `<DataGrid.Columns>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Just for information...

I had the problem because I added this style which seems very strange:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: I got the same error for the same reason. If I remove this, it goes away. How did you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code! It works. Really, I forgot to put   tags in an appropriate place.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CostsDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="260" Width="313" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinColumnWidth="35" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF7A7878" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF7A7878" RowHeight="35" Foreground="Black" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="CostsDataGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="состояние" Width="70" IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="OnChecked" Unchecked="OffChecked"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="расход" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="121" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="сумма" Binding="{Binding price}" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```