# Why can't I use "HasItems" property on ContextMenu with ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, contextmenu

I am using context menu on DataGrid.

I want each item will display context menu item by the entity that been right clicked.
In case that there is no entity the context menu item list will be empty so in this case I don't want the context menu to be visible to the user with empty items. (I see on empty rectangle that will confuse the user).

My code look like this:

```
<ContextMenu Name="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding DemoInstance.ContextMenuItems}"  
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource demo2Style}" >
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</ContextMenu>
```

when i am using it i get the exception:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: **Items collection must be empty before using
> ItemsSource."**

Why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `ContextMenu` style under `<ContextMenu.Style>` tags:

```
<ContextMenu Name="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding DemoInstance.ContextMenuItems}"  
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource demo2Style}" >
  <ContextMenu.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </ContextMenu.Style>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Doesn't the targetType in Style say it will apply to all ContextMenu? Do we have to explicitly include it into ContextMenu.Style?

Comment: Yeah it will. But the problem is OP has added style under ContextMenu. Ideally style should reside in parent or root element resources section so that it gets applied to all child Context Menu explicitly.

Comment: Now I see. Then I would suggest removing TargetType as it's not necessary in this case and it tricks some people like me and OP think it would apply to every ContextMenu.

Comment: `TargetType` has nothing to do with getting applied to all context menu's. If you omit setting `x:Key` then it gets applied to all child Context menu's. If you don't set `TargetType`, you have to use fully qualified property names otherwise XAML compiler will complain for not finding Visibility property.

Comment: Now I understand. What the OP does is defining a object inside the ContextMenu rather than telling the ContextMenu using that style. I learned something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your XAML. You added a `Style` as a child of the `ContextMenu`, and also binded it's `ItemsSource` property. (Setting both is not possible see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147707/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource-with-checkbox-control-in) for more info.)

But from your code I suspect that you most likely want something like this:

Resources part (where your `demo2Style` resides):

```
<Style x:Key="myCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>  
</Style>
```

And the `ContextMenu`:

```
    <ContextMenu Name="cm" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding DemoInstance.ContextMenuItems}" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource demo2Style}"
                 Style="{StaticResource myCustomStyle}" />
```